# Compiled enum constants

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor

Is Enum's in **C** replacement like `#define`?

For example if I have a flag list like:

```
enum{
 STATE_0 = 0x1<<0,
 STATE_1 = 0x1<<1,
 STATE_2 = 0x1<<2,
 STATE_3 = 0x1<<3,
 .
 .
 .
}
```

when the code compiled will the values have the evaluated results of statement or exact statement like using `#define`.

For example will STATE_2 be evaluated as `4` or `0x1<<2`?

PS: Reason of confusion comes from that none of the answers I have seen of `enum` vs `#define` question state that for simple expressions enum are faster than `#define`, if compiler optimizations are disabled.

Comment: It would be evaluated as `4`. Constant expressions in C are pre-evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums in C are not working like #defines. Enums are part of the language and are not processed by the pre-processor, so `STATE_2` will be evaluated as 4.